# How to determine if a property is required?

Tags: c#, .net

Given a class something like this:

```
public class MyClass : ValidationValues
{
    public string Foo { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Bar is required.")]
    public string Bar { get; set; }
    
    // and many more
}

public class ValidationValues
{
    public bool IsValid { get; set; } = true;
    public string InvalidReason { get; set; }
}
```

I need to determine if a property is required while looping over it as a generic list. By looking into the Watch, I've figured out one way, but it feels clunky, and I'm thinking it should be simpler.

For some context, this logic is inside of an Azure Function. So no Views, no MVC, etc. The function is a Blob Storage trigger that picks up a .CSV file with a | delimited list which gets deserialized into a `List<MyClass>`. We do not want to enforce the `Required` attributes at deserialization because we want more granular control.

So given a file like this:

```
value1 | |
value2 | something
```

What eventually gets sent back to the user is something like this:

```
[
    {
        "foo": "value1",
        "bar": "",
        "isValid": false,
        "InvalidReason" : "Bar is required"
    },
    {
        "foo": "value2",
        "bar": "something",
        "isValid": true,
        "InvalidReason" : ""
    }
]
```

Here's what I have now:

```
foreach (T item in itemList) // where 'itemList' is a List<T> and in this case T is MyClass
{
    foreach (PropertyInfo property in item.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
        if (property.CustomAttributes.ToList()[0].AttributeType.Name == "RequiredAttribute")
        {
             // validate, log, populate ValidationValues
        }
    }
}
```

This is the part I don't like:

```
property.CustomAttributes.ToList()[0].AttributeType.Name == "RequiredAttribute"
```

Sometimes when I figure out a coding challenge, I tell myself, "This is the way". But in this case, I'm pretty sure this isn't the way.

Comment: is `[0]` stable, even if it works now? what if you have multiple attributes? i think this is better `property.CustomAttributes.Any(p=>p is RequiredAttribute)`

Comment: So the field MUST be filled. Then why is it not in the constructor ? To simple solution ?

Comment: @LeiYang, good question. [Required] would need to be the first, you are correct. But also, this is a faily simple class, and [Required] will be the only attribute. But still, I agree that this feels fragile. Thus the post!

Comment: @Franck, Can you share more detail on what using the constructor would look like?

Comment: @CaseyCrookston you don't know how to make a constructor or you don't understand constructor parameters ?

Comment: @Franck: Deserialization uses the parameterless constructor, how would you make it use required parameters?

Comment: [`MemberInfo.GetCustomAttributes(Type, bool)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.reflection.memberinfo.getcustomattributes#system-reflection-memberinfo-getcustomattributes(system-type-system-boolean)).

Comment: Also [`GetCustomAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.customattributeextensions.getcustomattribute?view=net-6.0#system-reflection-customattributeextensions-getcustomattribute(system-reflection-memberinfo-system-type))

Comment: @PalleDue No you can do otherwise. You can use a non default constructor and if you do it properly you can also do it with class with multiple constructor and find the best to use to reload the object. You can simply find the constructor signature and pass the values of the serialized data to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can rewrite that line using `GetCustomAttibute`:

```
using System.Reflection;
foreach (T item in itemList) // where 'itemList' is a List<T> and in this case T is MyClass
{
    foreach (PropertyInfo property in item.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
        var attribute = property.GetCustomAttibute<RequiredAttribute>();
    }
}
```

Comment: They already have the property (or, rather theyre enumerating them) so this should just be `property.GetCustomAttibute<RequiredAttribute>()`

Comment: @Serhii, if you will change your answer to the comment by Jamiec, I'll mark it as correct

Comment: @CaseyCrookston done

Comment: if not required, `attribute` will be null?

Comment: @LeiYang yes, it is null

Answer (score 3):

Reflection is slow - or at least, relatively slow. So; the main important thing here is: don't do this per *instance*; you could either cache it per `Type` (from `GetType()`, or you could just use `T` and never even check `.GetType()` per instance, depending on your intent. This includes caching the properties that exist for a given type, and which are required. However, the real bonus points are to use meta-programming to emit - either at runtime, or at build-time via a "generator" - a method that *does exactly what you want, without any loops, tests, etc; i.e. in this case it might emit a method that does the equivalent of

```
void ValidateMyClass(MyClass obj)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhitespace(obj.Bar))
    {
        DoSomething("Bar is required.");
    }
}
```

This can be done in a variety of ways, including the `Expression` API, the emit API (`ILGenerator`), emitting C# and using `CSharpCodeProvider`, or the "generators" API.

Comment: Thanks Marc. I hear you on reflection being slow. However, speed is not a top concern here as this is an off-line process. No user looking at a UI waiting for a response. But mostly, unless I'm missing it, your example doesn't take into account the generic nature I'm looking for. I can't hard code the names of any properties, for example.

Comment: just from current answer i cannot get to know how the CustomAttibute is checked, can you write a little more to demonstrate the techniques metioned?

Comment: @CaseyCrookston the example was about *emitting* a method *at runtime*, per type; so there is no hard-coding; the point is that you would inspect the `T` once only (perhaps using a static constructor on a generic type for this part, i.e. `MetadataCache<T>.YourDataHere`), and *emit* the code. But: that is a performance thing; if you don't need that - don't go near it, it is a lot of work; instead, perhaps use a static constructor again, but just stash the `PropertyInfo` etc and perform the attribute analysis *once only*